# Can I run my command with out lein run?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I currently run a simple cli I wrote by calling: `lein run my-cli-command arg --option`

How can I call my command without needing to include lein run? This is what i'm after: `my-cli-command arg --option`

Do I need to convert it to an binary or executable and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to run just `my-cli-command arg --option`.

You can take lein out of the equation though by creating a Java archive:

```
lein uberjar
```

Then run the jar as you would any other:

```
java -jar target/my-cli-command-standalone.jar arg --option
```

`uberjar` will name the jar based on what you've called your project in `project.clj`, and will create a jar that relies on external dependencies, and one that doesn't (`standalone`).

Then, as @gary pointed out, you can stick the `java - jar ...` command in a .bat file, name it whatever you want, then run the bat directly. My `bat`-Fu is pretty weak, but there's likely a way to pass arguments to the bat and have them passed to the jar so you don't need to hard code the arguments.

Comment: this solution will allow you to then create a bat file or shell script named "my-cli-command" which you can call like you originally wanted to. the script would look like `java -jar target/my-cli-command-standalone.jar <arg 1> <arg 2>`

Comment: @Gary Yes. I'll try to add a blurb.

Answer (score 4):

As of Clojure 1.9 there are new CLI tools! See [this guide](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started) for installation. You can create an executable script like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/clojure
(println "Hello World! from" *ns*)
(require '[clojure.walk :as walk])
(walk/postwalk-demo {:woo ::yeah})
```

Then make the script executable and execute it:

```
$ chmod +x my_script
$ ./my_script
Hello World! from #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x1ebea008 user]
Walked: :woo
Walked: :user/yeah
Walked: [:woo :user/yeah]
Walked: {:woo :user/yeah}
```

Start-up time seems improved as well. It takes a little over a second to run a trivial script (just print a string) on a recent MBP:

```
time ./hello
Hello World!
./hello  1.51s user 0.12s system 184% cpu 0.887 total
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution IMHO now that 1.9 is out. Fair warning to emacs users, though: when you open such files, you won't be in `clojure-mode` by default!

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it, but I know [inlein](http://inlein.org) exists and it looks like what you need.

> Inlein is the easiest and fastest way to run Clojure scripts. You only have to inline your dependencies, add in a shebang line, and make the script file executable.

And a minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env inlein

'{:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]}

(println "hello world!")
```

Comment: this is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "binary payload" in shell script as described in https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable

Basically you can concatenate a shell script and your uberjar in a single shell script file and execute java in the script specifying that script as the jar file on the classpath - the example comes from the linked post:

Save your runner script in `stub.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
java=java
if test -n "$JAVA_HOME"; then
    java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
exec "$java" $java_args -jar $MYSELF "$@"
exit 1
```

Then concatenate it with your uberjar:

`cat stub.sh my-cli-command-uberjar.jar > my-cli-command && chmod +x my-cli-command`

Now you can run it directly:

`./my-cli-command args...`

There is also a lein plugin automating this process: [lein-binplus](https://github.com/BrunoBonacci/lein-binplus)